# High CPU Utilization with libGDX game

Tags: android, libgdx, cpu-usage, ads

I've been trying to solve my high CPU utilization problem for the past few weeks and I think I have pinpointed where the problem is coming from. I commented out all the ad initialization code from my AndroidLauncher class and CPU utilization is either close to nothing or at 0.0%. When the ad code is used, my CPU usage spikes between 10% - 20% and causing my Samsung Galaxy S4 to overheat if I just leave alone for awhile.

Would it be something to do with my calls back to my libGDX code using my custom implemented class (ActionResolver)? I'm also thinking, would my ad mediation have anything to do with it? Right now I have Google AdMob and mediating between google, millennial media and mobfox. Anyways, here's my android code:

I'm doing banner and interstitial ads and using some methods to hide and show them with calls in my ActionResolver. I also have in-app billing and I have code for Google Play Services that I removed from this code.

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements ActionResolver {

```
//Constants for phone sized ads (320x50)
private static final int BANNER_AD_WIDTH = 320;
private static final int BANNER_AD_HEIGHT = 50;

//this Activity
private Activity mActivity;

//Views
protected View gameView; //the libGDX gameView
protected AdView bannerView; //the view for the banner
protected InterstitialAd interstitialAd; //interstitial ad

//In-App Billing
private AndroidBilling androidBilling;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //this
    mActivity = this;

    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(mActivity);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    config.useImmersiveMode = true;
    config.useWakelock = true;

    // Create the libgdx View
    gameView = createGameView(config);

    // Create the banner View
    bannerView = createAdView();
    startAdvertising(bannerView);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);
    layout.addView(bannerView);

    //initialize interstitial ad
    interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mActivity);
    interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(AndroidConstants.AD_UNIT_ID_INTERSTITIAL);

    //hide ads till game starts
    showAds(false);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);

    //create the In-App Billing
    androidBilling = new AndroidBilling(mActivity);
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration config){
    //initialize window parameters
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    gameView = initializeForView(new PaperPig(this), config);  

    return gameView;
}

//creates the view for banner ad in the bottom
private AdView createAdView(){
    AdView bannerAd = new AdView(mActivity);
    bannerAd.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    bannerAd.setAdUnitId(AndroidConstants.AD_UNIT_ID_BANNER); //Secret

    //Calculate the size of the adView based on the ad size. Replace the width and height values if needed.
    int layoutWidth = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, BANNER_AD_WIDTH, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int layoutHeight = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, BANNER_AD_HEIGHT, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    //Create the layout parameters using the calculated adView width and height.
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutWidth, layoutHeight);

    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
    bannerAd.setLayoutParams(adParams);

    return bannerAd;
}

//request for new banner ad
private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest.Builder adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest.build()); 
}

// This is the callback that posts a message for the handler
@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
   handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
}

private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

protected Handler handler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS:
            {
                bannerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_ADS:
            {
                startAdvertising(bannerView); //refresh ad
                bannerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void showOrLoadInterstital() {
    try {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitialAd.show();
                }
                else {
                    AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                    interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}

//***IN-APP BILLING METHODS***//
public void inAppBilling(String iabCall){
    if(iabCall.equals("removeAds")){
        androidBilling.removeAds();
    } else if(iabCall.equals("purchase100")){
        androidBilling.purchase100Coconuts();
    } else if(iabCall.equals("purchase300")){
        androidBilling.purchase300Coconuts();
    } else if(iabCall.equals("purchase500")){
        androidBilling.purchase500Coconuts();
    } 
}

@Override
public boolean ismAdsRemoved() {
    return androidBilling.ismAdsRemoved();
}

@Override
public int getCoconutPoints() {
    return androidBilling.getCoconutPoints();
}

@Override
public void setCoconutPoints(int coconutPoints) {
    androidBilling.setCoconutPoints(coconutPoints);
}

@Override
public void setmAdsRemoved(boolean mAdsRemoved) {
    androidBilling.setmAdsRemoved(mAdsRemoved);
}

@Override
public boolean getSignedInGPGS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void loginGPGS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void logoutGPRS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void submitScoreGPGS(long score) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void unlockAchievementGPGS(String achievementId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void getLeaderboardGPGS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void getAchievementsGPGS() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //Resume Banner
    if (bannerView != null) bannerView.resume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //Pause Banner
    if (bannerView != null) bannerView.pause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //Destroy Banner
    if (bannerView != null) bannerView.destroy();

    //Destroy IAB
    androidBilling.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      androidBilling.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }


  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mActivity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mActivity);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    Button b1 = new Button(mActivity);
    b1.setText("Quit the Pig?");
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
      }
    });
    ll.addView(b1);

    dialog.setContentView(ll);
    dialog.show();
  }
```

}

My game is here if there is anyone who knows or has any tools that can help me figure out exactly what is happening.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.myertha.paperpig.android

Comment: Just FYI: Ad SDKs use a WebView to show the ad so resource utilization is up there.

Comment: So, are you saying it's inevitable to have high CPU utilization if I have ads?

Comment: Ads use one of the heaviest objects in Android, so if you use them during gameplay (doubtful-but I haven't checked) or you are getting ads from all of your networks and not releasing resources that may be direction of investigation. Good luck.

Comment: This is a known issue... I already contacted Google AdMob group and as of Oct 15, 2014, AdMob continues to cause high CPU Utilization 

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/1aidjtsin8A